# Caffe compilation fails: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64?

Tags: caffe

If I try building the newest version of Caffe, it leads to this error:

```
$ make all
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "caffe::Net<float>::Forward(float*)", referenced from:
      test() in caffe.o
      time() in caffe.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
```

I'm building on osx, OpenBLAS, and CPU_ONLY. I found a [kind of similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890137/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-for-caffe-build) on here but it appears to have been a resolved issue, and I'm not getting the exact same error, though perhaps it's related? I can also build and run an older version of Caffe from a month ago, so I think something has changed very recently.

Any ideas on how to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

It shows a link problem when compile.On osx this problem will happen usually.I guess the problem happened in `Makefile.config`.You can change to

```
# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
CUSTOM_CXX := g++
```

and confirm some path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Its now resolved.
Do check if you already have a libcaffe.so in your system library paths (maybe /usr/local/lib). If so, delete the existing libcaffe.so and build again.